# What is the best way to wait in C#?

Tags: c#

I am making a console application that is to execute only a couple of commands such as `whoami`. The issue i am coming up against is how to make `Please wait...` Wait X (e.g. 5) seconds without halting the thread, then continue

Comment: What kind of event loop are you running to avoid freezing?

Comment: i'm not using any method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a one-shot timer to do it. For example:

```
static int main(...)
{
    System.Threading.Timer clearTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(
        (s) => { Console.Clear(); },
        null,
        5000,
        Timeout.Infinite);
    // do other stuff
}
```

That creates a timer that will fire once after five seconds.